# How to change the Background Color of the Ant-Design 'Select' component?

Tags: reactjs, select, antd, background-color

Suppose I want to change the standard white background color of the Select component dynamically based on selection. I found a solution
on the internet `.ant-select-selection { background-color: green; }` but this is static.

It should be like this:

[image]

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd-4-24-1-forked-pop1xx?file=/demo.tsx) link

Here is a sample code:

```
const RBICOptions = [
  {
    background: "#00CC00",
    color: "#fff",
    title: "Low",
    value: "low"
  },
  {
    background: "#FFFF00",
    color: "#000",
    title: "Medium",
    value: "medium"
  },
  {
    background: "#FFC000",
    color: "#000",
    title: "High",
    value: "high"
  },
  {
    background: "#FF0000",
    color: "#fff",
    title: "Very High",
    value: "very_high"
  }
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedIPSS, setSelectedIPSS] = useState("#fff");
  console.log("selectedIPSS", selectedIPSS);

  return (
    <Select
      style={{
        width: "50vw",
        marginBottom: "5%",
        backgroundColor: selectedIPSS
      }}
      onChange={(_, option) => {
        setSelectedIPSS("style" in option ? option.style.background : "#fff");
      }}
    >
      {RBICOptions.map((op) => (
        <Select.Option
          key={op.value}
          value={op.value}
          style={{ background: op.background, color: op.color }}
        >
          {op.title}
        </Select.Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

Please help me out with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the `ant-select` class already defines a white background. You can remove it with setting the style to `inherit`:

```css
.ant-select:not(.ant-select-customize-input) .ant-select-selector {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd-4-24-1-forked-rzln9z?file=/index.css:0-99